# The map function in TextField does not work if it is located in the component material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The map function in TextField does not work if it is located in the component material-ui

I have two TextFields in the first one the radio button works, in the second one the radio button does not work. How to do if the map function is located in a separate component to use the radio button?
if you try to replace the value in the first example, it will change correctly, in the second example it does not work. The only difference is that in the second example map is a separate file

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-snow-bmbcn2?file=/src/Test.js
[image]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import MapCastom from "./MapCastom";

const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD",
    label: "$"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR",
    label: "€"
  },
  {
    value: "BTC",
    label: "฿"
  },
  {
    value: "JPY",
    label: "¥"
  }
];

export default function SelectTextFields() {
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-select-currency"
          select
          label="Select"
          defaultValue="EUR"
          helperText="Please select your currency"
        >
          {currencies.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </div>

      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-select-currency"
          select
          label="Select"
          defaultValue="EUR"
          helperText="Please select your currency"
        >
          <MapCastom data={currencies} />
        </TextField>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}


import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

const MapCastom = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default MapCastom;
```

Comment: Why not use https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here most likely you are encountering the warning

> MUI: You have provided an out-of-range

which means that during first rendering select value doesn't see possible options.

One way to fix it is to not use a component for this, already what you need is an array so you can replace `MapCastom` with this function :

```js
const MapCastom = (data) => {
  return data.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ));
};
```

and call it this way :

```js
<TextField
  id="outlined-select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  defaultValue="EUR"
  helperText="Please select your currency"
>
  {MapCastom(currencies)}
</TextField>;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for the MenuItem to work, it has to be a direct descendent of Select. One workaround is to use a function to return MenuItems instead of a component. [Github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/31006)